# How to hide HTML template if a variable value is undedfined/null?

Tags: angular, hidden

I have used ngFor to display my data. And i want to hide a div if variable value from ngFor is empty/undefined. My code is below. Can anybody help.

```
<li *ngFor="let parcel of dataSource;">

   <span hidden="parcel.ID==''">{{parcel.refrence }}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: also the syntax for hidden is `[hidden]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) since your parcelID is undefined your condition should be `*ngIf="parcel.ID"`

```
<li *ngFor="let parcel of dataSource;">
   <span *ngIf="parcel.ID">{{parcel.refrence }}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Is it not possible thru [hidden]

Comment: It is possible, but `*ngIf` will remove the `<div>` from the dom whereas `[hidden]` will just add a CSS style : `display : none` to it.

Comment: Your above code will show the span if parcel.ID is empty right?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#ngIf

Comment: I tried with *ngIf="parcel.ID!=''". Bu tit does not work.

Comment: no.. @GreenComputers the key difference is ngIf removes the entire part of the DOM

Comment: @GreenComputers Is your parcel.ID an empty string or is it undefined ?

Comment: @YounesM: It is undefined.

Comment: @GreenComputers You should use `*ngIf="parcel.ID"` then.

Answer (score 0):

use this code -

```
<li *ngFor="let parcel of dataSource;">
   <span [hidden]="parcel.ID !== ''">{{parcel.refrence }}</span>
</li>
```

or

```
<li *ngFor="let parcel of dataSource;">
   <span *ngIf="parcel.ID == ''">{{parcel.refrence }}</span>
</li>
```

> the syntax for hidden is [hidden]

Comment: In both of these cases span will be hidden/will not appear. but, li placeholder will always be there. So, it won't solve the actual issue.