# How to check if a variable is null in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to make a simple app that reads a WP-API. My problem is that if the post doesn't have a featured image the variable becomes "null" and then the app crashes. Here is my code

```
<ion-card  *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="onSelectPost(post)">
<img [src]="post.better_featured_image.source_url"/> \\Here is the problem
<ion-card-content>
  <ion-card-title>
    {{post.title.rendered}}
  </ion-card-title>
  <p [innerHtml]="post.excerpt.rendered"></p>
</ion-card-content>
```

Is there any way to check if the variable is null and then hide it?

Comment: *ngIf is your friend. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif

Comment: @vais mark if the answer helped

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide HTML template if a variable value is undedfined/null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971883/how-to-hide-html-template-if-a-variable-value-is-undedfined-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a safe navigation operator which will check if the variable has data, change it as

```
<img [src]="post?.better_featured_image?.source_url"/>
```

**EDIT:**

As @JB Nizet suggested better to use ***ngIf**  since the above method keeps the **`img`** element in the dom, with a null src.

change it as

```
  <img *ngIf="post.better_featured_image" [src]="post.better_featured_image.source_url"/>
```

Comment: Why would you want an image with a null src?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I want to check if the src is null and change it with a placeholder. Can I do that with a "if"?

Comment: @Sajeetharan because it suggests using an image with a null src, whereas it should either not have an image at all, or have an image with an alternative src. I will happily remove the downvote if you improve the answer. (it also adds a useless ? after post)

Comment: @JBNizet oh thanks for the explanation. is not the same with ngIf as well?

Comment: No. An ngIf would remove the image. Your answer leaves the img element in the dom, with a null src.

Comment: @JBNizet i had a wrong assumption on safe navigation operator then, thanks!

Comment: The condition should be `post.better_featured_image`, since that's what is potentially null.

Comment: And the *ngIf should be on the img element. No need to wrap it into a div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***typeof*** keyword to find out the value and using a condition like if check if the value is null or not.